# Can I register with Google for markup emails without sending hundreds of emails before?

Tags: google-schemas

I read the guidelines and I have a problem with "Consistent history of sending a high volume of mail from your domain (order of hundred emails a day minimum to Gmail) for a few weeks at least." The thing is, I need RSVP buttons for an internal application that manages leaves and holidays, and the particular email address we created for our app does not send any other messages. So I can't possibly send "hundreds of emails" in order to prove that I'm not spamming anyone. If I describe the situation in the registration form, can I get a pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SilviaFilip, I see that you've mentioned internal app. If your domain is a [Google Apps](https://apps.google.com/intx/en_us/) for Work/Education domain, you can request to have that [registered](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1). This will give you capability to send Gmail schemas internally to users within your domain.

If you need to send to external domains this will not fit your use case. Additionally, if you don't have a Google Apps domain, unfortunately, it looks like you will have to fulfill their [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#email_sender_quality_guidelines).